# Вычесть объект из объекта. Преобразование типов

Tags: c#

Сделал свой тип(класс) на подобие типа очередь 'Queue'. Добавил свойство 
`public static object[] Elements` 
Создается экземпляр класса 'Queue', в массив заносятся разные данные разных типов(int,string). Создается второй экземпляр 'Queue' отличный от первого. Необходимо реализовать метод сложения и вычитания очередей. Через перегрузку операторов. С перегрузкой более менее понятно. Загвоздка в методе: я не могу сделать просто

```
myQueue1.Elements[i] - myQueue2.Elements[i]
```

Потому что, c# не знает как вычитать объекты. Не могу разобраться с преобразованием типов, как это сделать?
Код моего метода:

```
public static myQueue Minus(myQueue q1, myQueue q2)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Elements.Length; i++)
        {
            if (q1.elements[i].GetType() == q2.elements[i].GetType())
            {
                //Если типы равны - вычитаем q2 из q1
            }
        }
        return q1;
    }
```

Comment: Как должно работать вычитание для, например, строк?

Comment: Забросил этот вопрос до того, как найду решение текущего. Походу зря, их толком и не вычесть, получается использовать только числа? Значит, можно все тупо конвертировать в 'Int' без задней мысли? Почему тогда в задании очередь, ведь это некая коллекция типа 'object'..В целом вы мне сильно помогли. Хотя, если использовать int и double. Не помешало бы такое преобразование.

Comment: Расскажите, откуда взялась задача. Возможно, вам нужно завести generic-очередь и передавать операцию снаружи.

Comment: Сложение и вычитание очередей это частный случай сложения и вычитания множеств, это делается элементарно. Если же Вам нужно *другое* сложение/вычитания, то поясните, что Вы имеете в виду.

Comment: Да я и сам толком не знаю. Это дз. "Создать объект очередь с перегруженными +,+=, добавление элемента в очередь и сложение очередей, -- для извлечения из очереди, - для вычитания очередей". Добавление и извлечение получилось, с остальным проблемы. Буду у преподавателя спрашивать, дает в конце непонятные задания без пояснений, а вопросов много возникает и часто что-то не так реализовывается. Объяснял он про перегрузку операторов, про очереди и generic или множества  не говорил.

Comment: @AgasiMkhitaryan скорее всего под вычитанием имелось ввиду именно вычитание двух очередей (как множеств), а не попарное вычитание элементов. Т.е. получение такой очереди, в которой есть элементы из первой очереди, которых нет во второй.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @AgasiMkhitaryan скорее всего под вычитанием имелось ввиду именно
>   вычитание двух очередей (как множеств), а не попарное вычитание
>   элементов. Т.е. получение такой очереди, в которой есть элементы из
>   первой очереди, которых нет во второй. – PashaPash

Если это так, то вот вам пример реализации оператора, на примере существующего класса `Queue<T>`. Решение не оптимальное, т.к. не указаны ограничения для задачи. Просто демонстрация перегрузки оператора и вычитания очередей как множеств.

```
public static Queue<int> operator - (Queue<int> a, Queue<int> b)
{
    Queue<int> result = new Queue<int>();
    foreach (var current in a)
    {
        bool flag = true;
        foreach (var test in b)
        {
            if (current == test)
            {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag) result.Enqueue(current);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Теорию о разности множеств можно почитать, например, на вики: [Разность множеств](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2)